# In SQL query how can I use variable which has value of input to save in database

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sqlite

(sorry for such basic question but I'm total newbie)
In SQL query how can I use variable which has value of input to save in database
Example>

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

When using
 `let variable = document.getElementById("something");`
In my db-manage.js I'm getting error when I'm trying to declare a veriable assigned with value of HTML input

And

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using express you can do something like this

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')

const con = mysql.createConnection({configObject}) 

    app.get('/add', (req, res) => {
        const sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name SET ?'
        con.query(sql, req.body, err => {
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send('post added to table_name.')
        })
    })
```